# Psalms for Festivals

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, chagim-holidays, shir-shel-yom

There are Nuschaot (eg the Gra's) that recite specific Psalms on individual Festival days, instead of the Psalm of the day of the week. Presumably this is based on what was done in the Temple. Where can I find a list of these, with their corresponding Festival days?

Comment: For the record, the Gemara doesn’t identify the song the Levites sang in the Temple for everything. Not sure what the source is for the entire list.

Comment: @doni Masekhet Sofrim

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Mark!

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/images/shirshelyom.pdf) is a link to a chart of the Gra's order. At the top of the chart three regulations are listed:

1. Two psalms are not recited on any given day.
2. The psalm for the New Moon supersedes any other psalm.
3. The psalm for the Sabbath supersedes the psalms of festivals and Hanukkah.