# Who had the authority to change the Shir Shel Yom of Chanukah?

Tags: chanuka, beis-hamikdash, shir-shel-yom

As has been pointed out [previously](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86165/501), the source of which Shir Shel Yom to say on Chanukah (Psalms 30) is in [Ch. 18:2 of Masechet Sofrim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.18.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he).

Masechet Sofrim seems to make a break between those Shir Shel Yom said in the Mikdash ([Ch. 18:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.18.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he)) and some others, like Chanukah.

I was wondering: **What did the Levi'im sing on Chanuka in the Mikdash? If it was Psalms 30 then who had the authority to change it from the regular schedule** sung for about 600 years, until the Chanuka miracle, **to a new one?**

---

Masechet Sofrim Ch. 18:1-2

> **1:**
>   למה אמרו שיהא אומרין בכל חודש וחודש כרשב"ל בעא קמיה רבי יוחנן מהו לומר שיר בלא נסכים אמר ליה נשמעיניה מן הדא בזה ובזה הלוים עומדין על הדוכן ואומרים (תהלים צד) וישב עליהם את אונם א"ל רשב"ל מזמור ומוסף מי קודם מחורתא מילתא שהמזמור קודם לפיכך נהגו העם לומר מזמורים בעונתן (כלומר בעתן) דתנינן תמן **שיר שהלוים אומרים בבית המקדש** ביום הראשון היו אומרים (שם כד) לה׳ הארץ ומלואה תבל ויושבי בה כו׳: בשני היו אומרים (שם מח) גדול ה׳ ומהולל מאד כו': בשלישי היו אומרים (שם פב) אלהים נצב בעדת אל כו׳: ברביעי היו אומרים (שם צד) אל נקמות ה׳ כו': בחמישי היו אומרים (שם פא) הרנינו לאלהים עוזנו כו׳: בששי היו אומרים (שם צג) ה׳ מלך גאות לבש כו׳: בשבת היו אומרים (שם צב) מזמור שיר ליום השבת לעתיד לבא ליום שכולו שבת ומנוחה לחיי העולמים שכל המזכיר פסוק בעונתו מעלה עליו כאילו בונה מזבח חדש ומקריב עליו קרבן:‏
>
> **2:**
>   **בחנוכה** (שם ל) ארוממך ה' בפורים (שם ז) שגיון לדוד ביום הראשון של פסח (שם קלה) הללו את שם ה' (וי"א (שם פג) אלהים אל דמי לך) וכן חולו של מועד אלא בימים הראשונים של פסח הוא צריך לומר יהי כבוד ה' וכל העם בעמידה עד וברוך שם כבודו לעולם ויושבין ואומרים כל ענין של מזמורות ובי"ט האחרון של פסח הלל הגדול ואיזהו הלל הגדול (שם קלו) הודו לה' כי טוב הודו לאלהי האלהים ונהגו העם לומר הלל הגדול אף ע"פ שאינו מן המובחר:‏

Comment: There was a regular schedule for 1000 years? How do you know that?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I assume that it started in the Mishkan - if not, then it was only 600 years, when the 1st Mikdash was built - do you have any info either way - or another option?

Comment: Oh, they sang for 1000 years. Who said it was a regular schedule? They didn't sing Asaf's song in the Mishkan, for instance

Comment: @DoubleAA - true - so then the שיר שהלוים אומרים בבית המקדש was implemented by Shlomo? Or only in the 2nd Mikdash? Do we have a source either way?

Comment: I have no reason to assume it was anything but a Minhag of the second temple period that regularly got uprooted for all sorts of occasions (visiting king, burning a Parah Adummah that day, Megillat Taanit, thanks for rain, fast for rain, or anything like that). Why assume anything stronger without basis? In fact your question seems to prove me right! In any event whoever had the authority to create Chanukkah with Berakhot and all had the authority to change the schedule: the Sanhedrin.

Comment: I think this might be a misreading of the source. All of these psalms are preceded by the words **נהגו העם לומר מזמורים בעונתן**, meaning that saying these psalms nowadays is a custom. The reason for this custom is quoted explicitly (דתנינן תמן) from the Mishnah ([Tamid 7:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%96_%D7%93)), which gives the psalms the Levites said on each day of the week. The words שיר שהלוים אומרים בבית המקדש are quoted directly from this Mishnah, not in order to say that all of the psalms given are the ones the Levites sang.