# What are the Shir Shel Yom for Yamim Tovim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, yom-tov, shir-shel-yom

I recently came across Sukkah 55a, which lists the Shirei Shel Yom for Chol HaMoed Sukkos. Are there any other Gemaras which discuss the Shirei Shel Yom of other Yamim Tovim? What are they? Are there any that we have a tradition for which are not in the Gemara?

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86156/psalms-for-festivals https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/source-for-shir-shel-yom-of-the-gra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maseches Sofrim (which was written by the Amoraim of Eretz Yisroel) 18,2-3 there is a list of Mizmorim for every Yom tov

> ב**חנוכה** (שם ל) ארוממך ה'
>    ב**פורים** (שם ז) שגיון לדוד
>    ב**יום הראשון של פסח** (שם קלה) הללו את שם ה' (וי"א (שם פג) אלהים אל דמי לך
>    וכן **חולו של מועד** אלא בימים הראשונים של פסח הוא צריך לומר יהי כבוד ה' וכל העם בעמידה עד וברוך שם כבודו לעולם ויושבין ואומרים כל ענין של מזמורות
>   וב**י"ט האחרון של פסח** הלל הגדול ואיזהו הלל הגדול (שם קלו) הודו לה' כי טוב הודו לאלהי האלהים ונהגו העם לומר הלל הגדול אף ע"פ שאינו מן המובחר:
>   וב**חג השבועות** (תהלים כט) הבו לה׳ בני אלים
>   ב**ט׳ באב** בארבע פסוקים משל ירמיה (יד) המאוס מאסת את (דבר ה׳) [יהודה] עד כי אתה עשית [את] כל אלה. ושני מזמורים הללו אלהים באו גוים בנחלתך (תהלים עט) ועל נהרות בבל (שם קלז) אע"פ שבכל מקום מקדימין דברי קדושה לדברי קבלה בזה דברי קבלה מקדימין לדברי קדושה:
>   וב**ראש השנה** אומר כל העמים תקעו כף (תהילים מ״ז:ב)׳
>   '(ב**יום הכפורים** ברכי נפשי (שם קד) וממעמעקים קראתיך ה׳ (שם קל
>   '(ב**חג הסוכות** נודע ביהודה (שם עו
>   ב**יום השמיני** למנצח על השמינית (שם ו) ואם אינו בקי בהן אומר אודה ה׳ בכל לבי (שם ט) ודיו

Traditionally in standard Ashkenazi Shuls (excluding those that follow the Gra there is a link to his list in Joelks comment)  we don't say any Mizmor other than the Daily ones, except on Rosh Chodesh where we add Tehillim 104, Chanuka Tehillim 30 (mentioned above from source).
 It happens to be that on Rosh Hashana we do say Tehillim 47 mentioned above before blowing the Shofar, and on Yom Kippur we say Tehillim 130 before Bircos kerias Shema mentioned above,Tehillim 135 mentioned above on Rishon Shel Pesach during Pesukei Dezimra, and Tehillim 136 mentioned above on Acharon Shel Pesach during Pesukei Dezimra.