# Is there a chart for the Shir Shel Yom for chagim in English?

Tags: minhag, tehillim

Individuals have been kind enough to post in at least two previous questions a link to the chart for the Gra's Shir Shel Yom for  the chagim which is
http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/images/shirshelyom.pdf

The two previous questions which addressed this issue (there may be others) are:
[Psalms for Festivals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86156/psalms-for-festivals)

[Source for Shir Shel Yom of the Gra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/source-for-shir-shel-yom-of-the-gra)

My question is: Has this chart be translated into English and, if so, what is the link to it? If not, is there anything that might be helpful for non-Ivrit readers?
MANY THANKS for any assistance.
Shavua tov and CHAG PESACH KASHER V'SAMEACH!

Answer (score 1):

some artscroll tehillims have it in the back

Comment: Thanks very much, Saon. I did check a couple versions with no luck. But, as a result of your answer, I went back and checked another one. Lo and behold, I did find the list. MANY THANKS to you!!!